# Trying to print unicode characters C++ assert failed

Tags: c++, unicode, ascii-art

I've been trying to print Unicode characters. I'm new to C++. I'm on Windows 10 and using Visual Studio 2019.

I'm trying to print the following art in a console application:

```
██╗███╗░░██╗░██████╗░█████╗░███╗░░██╗██╗████████╗██╗░░░██╗
██║████╗░██║██╔════╝██╔══██╗████╗░██║██║╚══██╔══╝╚██╗░██╔╝
██║██╔██╗██║╚█████╗░███████║██╔██╗██║██║░░░██║░░░░╚████╔╝░
██║██║╚████║░╚═══██╗██╔══██║██║╚████║██║░░░██║░░░░░╚██╔╝░░
██║██║░╚███║██████╔╝██║░░██║██║░╚███║██║░░░██║░░░░░░██║░░░
╚═╝╚═╝░░╚══╝╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═╝░░╚══╝╚═╝░░░╚═╝░░░░░░╚═╝░░░
```

I used `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);` which let me print it, but when trying to print some text, I get an assertion failed.

My code is this:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

void banner() {

    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wprintf(L"      ██╗███╗░░██╗░██████╗░█████╗░███╗░░██╗██╗████████╗██╗░░░██╗\n");
    wprintf(L"      ██║████╗░██║██╔════╝██╔══██╗████╗░██║██║╚══██╔══╝╚██╗░██╔╝\n");
    wprintf(L"      ██║██╔██╗██║╚█████╗░███████║██╔██╗██║██║░░░██║░░░░╚████╔╝░\n");
    wprintf(L"      ██║██║╚████║░╚═══██╗██╔══██║██║╚████║██║░░░██║░░░░░╚██╔╝░░\n");
    wprintf(L"      ██║██║░╚███║██████╔╝██║░░██║██║░╚███║██║░░░██║░░░░░░██║░░░\n");
    wprintf(L"      ╚═╝╚═╝░░╚══╝╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═╝░░╚══╝╚═╝░░░╚═╝░░░░░░╚═╝░░░\n");
}
void login(std::string username, std::string password) {

}
void menu() {
    printf("Thank you For choosing Insanity");
}
int main()
{
    bool loggedin = false;
    if (loggedin) {
        banner();
        menu();

    }
    else {
        banner();
        printf("Please Login...\n");
        printf("Username :");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the specific text of the assertion that's being failed? What exactly happens when you launch the app?

Comment: It's important to include the exact text of errors that you get, such as the assertion failure you claim to have.  Please edit the question and add the text of the assertion failure message.  And please make sure to include such error messages in any future posts you make here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: hello @NathanPierson i got what i wanted to do with Ted Lyngmo answer thanks for your help!

Comment: @Wyck thanks i'll keep that in mind i already got help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to mix modes and `cout` with `wcout`.

You could try to stick with `std::wcout` only and set the mode directly at program start - before you've made any output.

This could possibly work:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#include <clocale>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const std::wstring greeting =
LR"aw(
██╗███╗░░██╗░██████╗░█████╗░███╗░░██╗██╗████████╗██╗░░░██╗
██║████╗░██║██╔════╝██╔══██╗████╗░██║██║╚══██╔══╝╚██╗░██╔╝
██║██╔██╗██║╚█████╗░███████║██╔██╗██║██║░░░██║░░░░╚████╔╝░
██║██║╚████║░╚═══██╗██╔══██║██║╚████║██║░░░██║░░░░░╚██╔╝░░
██║██║░╚███║██████╔╝██║░░██║██║░╚███║██║░░░██║░░░░░░██║░░░
╚═╝╚═╝░░╚══╝╚═════╝░╚═╝░░╚═╝╚═╝░░╚══╝╚═╝░░░╚═╝░░░░░░╚═╝░░░
)aw";

void banner() {
    std::wcout << greeting;
}

void menu() {
    std::wcout << L"Thank you For choosing Insanity";
}

int main() {
    const char CP_UTF_16LE[] = ".1200";
    setlocale(LC_ALL, CP_UTF_16LE);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);

    bool loggedin = false;
    if (loggedin) {
        banner();
        menu();
    } else {
        banner();
        std::wcout << L"Please Login...\nUsername :";
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! i didn't expected a soon answer and accurate one works as i want

Comment: @Rodrigo Glad that it worked! You're welcome!